# meteor how to see which user added the image in the collection

Tags: meteor

I have the following code which I use for the security of my app. It's a simple image gallery with ratings etc.. I want to know how to check which user added the current target image in the database so only he could delete it from there. By now I only know how to check if this user is logged in. I have the following code:

```
 Images.allow({
  insert:function(userId, doc){
    if (Meteor.user()) {//they are logged in
      //force the image to be owned by the user
      doc.createdBy = userId
      if (userId != doc.createdBy) {//the user tryies to do something which is not allowed
        return false;
      }
      else {
        return true;
      }
    }
    else {// the user is not logged in so we do not allow him to use our data
      return false;
    }
  },

  remove: function(userId, Images){
    if (Meteor.user()) {//they are logged in
      //force the image to be owned by the user
      doc.createdBy = userId
      if (userId != doc.createdBy) {//the user tryies to do something which is not allowed
        return false;
      }
      else {
        return true;
      }
    }
    else {// the user is not logged in so we do not allow him to use our data
      return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I want to update only the remove function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some mistakes:

- The arguments to remove() should also be `remove( userId, doc )`
- You shouldn't modify the doc in the allow functions.
  (The `doc.createdBy = userId` statement belongs in the client side code that does the saving)
- Then if your client side saving code sets `<doc>.createdBy = Meteor.userId()` you can use it in the remove function as is already done.

Comment: Thank you, the answer was really helpful. I did the changes so now everything works.